# VMWare Workstation and Windows 10: can't connect to a server hosted on VM

Tags: kubernetes, vmware-workstation, kubeadm, bare-metal, nginx-ingress

I have a private 2 nodes Kubernetes cluster configured on VMWare Workstation 15. I'm using MetalLB and Calico.
Ingress service and ingress look like:

```
xxx@c1-cp1:~/Desktop$ kubectl get svc -n ingress-controller-2
NAME                                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
wsnginx-ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.109.117.222   192.168.44.136   80:30167/TCP,443:30680/TCP   24h
wsnginx-ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.105.103.165   <none>           443/TCP                      24h
xxx@c1-cp1:~/Desktop$ kubectl get ing apollo-ingress
NAME             CLASS     HOSTS                ADDRESS          PORTS   AGE
apollo-ingress   wsnginx   test.xxx.com   192.168.44.136   80      3h17m
```

I am using Nat Network Adapter and static IPS. I have port forwarding configured as following

[image]

`curl -D- http://192.168.44.136 -H 'Host: test.xxx.com'` from VM, returns 200 status but I cannot manage to access it from host machine Win10 on `127.0.0.1:8080` as I get a `404 NGINX NotFound`.

Could you please help me out? what am I doing wrong? How else could I expose it in my private network?
Thank you!

---

**UPDATE**
I am not sure if this is the right way, but I managed to connect from the host machine, by changing a bit the Ingress resource. I put in comments the host parameter, as

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: apollo-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: wsnginx
  rules:
    #- host: test.xxx.com
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: apollo-service
                port: 
                  number: 80
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
```

and now my ingress looks like this

```
NAMESPACE   NAME                                                   CLASS     HOSTS                        ADDRESS          PORTS     AGE
default     ingress.networking.k8s.io/apollo-ingress               wsnginx   *                            192.168.44.136   80        3h31m
```

It seems that I can access it now from my host machine as well. I am having a Rest API so I've just opened it from browser `http://127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: Hi Oana welcome to S.F. You didn't include the actual test command for your Win10 example, but for clarity: Ingress resources are entirely host-header virtual hosted, meaning (just as you did with your `curl`) you _must_ include a `host:` header so the ingress controller knows how to route your request. Good luck

Comment: hi @mdaniel ! thank you :) Well, i was just trying to open it in browser (as there is a REST API) --> 127.0.0.1:8080; but i made it work in the meantime by removing the host value from ingress manifest   
`rules:
    #- host: test.xxx.com
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: apollo-service
                port: 
                  number: 80`
 Is this ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a simple issue of missing HTTP header.

First, short explanaition:
Whenever a `Host` field is specified in Ingress manifest, only connections from that host will be accepted. This information is extracted form `Host` HTTP header. If you do not specify `Host` field in Ingress manifest, requests from all sources will be accepted.

You did sent the request correctly the first time

```text
curl -D- http://192.168.44.136 -H 'Host: test.xxx.com'
```

But forgot to do this the second time.
Powershell equivalent of the above is

```ps
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://127.0.0.1 -Headers @{"Host"="test.xxx.com"}
```

This is all nice and easy when done from command line, but sending request from web browser is a tad harder. Web broswers does not allow you to modify a request, to include proper `Host` header, by default. However such functionality can be achieved with extensions:

- [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en) for Chrome/Chromium
- [Modify Header Value](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-header-value/) for Firefox